Can't install tensortrade on M2 mac
I am trying to install TensorTrade on an M2 mac.  It fails becuase it can't install tensorflow 2.9.3
  - Installing tensorflow (2.9.3): Failed

I have already installed:
tensorflow-macos = "2.9.2"
tensorflow-metal = "0.5.0"

Is there a prior version I can use?

tensorflow 2.9 -- 2.12 does not exist for M2 processors. More precisely, Google did not build and publish the packages on PyPI. You can see this for yourself: https://pypi.org/simple/tensorflow/ (Look for packages of the form macosx_*_arm64). My understanding is that at the time when tensorflow 2.9 was published (cca 2022), M1, M2 chips didn't exist, or at least they were not popular, and so Google didn't build tensorflow for these processors. Later Google didn't bother to publish these packages and assumed that people would use newer version of tensorflow instead.
Your best bet is to install a later version of tensorflow, i.e., 2.13 or later.
